# Bootstrap 3: Can 'row' and 'col-xx-xx' classes be assigned to non-block leven elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Is it advisable to give Bootstrap 3 classes to non-block level elements such as span? What are the best practices in this area? I am still to see an answer to this question anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Since those bootstrap classes only specifies css properties listed below, technically it is possible to use them on non-block elements, but you have to additionally set display: block; for these elements. But I don't think it is  advisable, html elements must be used with taking in account of their purpose, as it described in html w3c standard.

for .row:

```
margin-left
margin-right
```

for col-xx-xx:

```
  position
  min-height
  padding-left
  padding-right
  width
```